Raspberry pi with i2c smbus2
I have a question regarding controlling my LCD1602 with my Raspberry Pi 5. To do this I am using the smbus2 library. Here is my code that uses the smbus library to control the i2c system:
try:
    import smbus2
    LCD = smbus2.SMBus(1)
    address = 0x27
    IR = 0
    DR = 1
    ASCII_WORD = "HELLO"

    LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x80, force=None) #set the cursor at the beginning of line 1

    for char in ASCII_WORD:
        LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x10, force=None) #set the cursor 1 column left
        for bit in range(8):
            LCD.write_byte_data(address, DR, ord(char) >> (7 - bit), force=None)#write ASCII character
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x01, force=None)#clear display
    LCD.close()


Here is a great link in which I received most of the data bit values from: https://www.electronicsforu.com/technology-trends/learn-electronics/16x2-lcd-pinout-diagram
This is what is going on in my code:

Set the cursor position.
Write the ASCII of the character I want.

Issue:
The result from this code was unexpected, the cursor position was on the 5th column of the second row and there was a ≣ sign on the first row second column. I soon realised that the for bit in range(8): was unnecessary because the smbus2 library handles converting the decimal values to binary and sending that bit by bit (Please correct me if I’m wrong). This extra loop is likely causing duplicates of ASCII codes.
Debugged code:
try:
    import time
    import smbus2
    LCD = smbus2.SMBus(1)
    address = 0x27
    IR = 0
    DR = 1
    ASCII_WORD = "HELLO"

    LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x80, force=None) #set the cursor at the beginning of line 1
    for char in ASCII_WORD:
        LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x10, force=None) #set the cursor 1 column left
            LCD.write_byte_data(address, DR, ord(char) >> (7 - bit), force=None)#write ASCII character
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x01, force=None)#clear display
    LCD.close()

New Issue:
This code creates an issue where the whole LCD backlight turns off. It could be that the whole LCD turns off, but the power LED stays on.
Debugging:
I tried removing the except block as I thought maybe it was just clearing the display - the backlight was still turning off when I ran the code. I also tried isolating each LCD.write_byte_data() to see if one singular one was causing the issue - each isolated one was causing the backlight to turn off. I then found the ">> (7-bit)" line was still in my code so I removed it. Here is my revised code:
try:
    import time
    import smbus2
    LCD = smbus2.SMBus(1)
    address = 0x27
    IR = 0
    DR = 1
    ASCII_WORD = "HELLO"

    LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x80, force=None) #set the cursor at the beginning of line 1
    for char in ASCII_WORD:
        LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x10, force=None) #set the cursor 1 column left
            LCD.write_byte_data(address, DR, ord(char), force=None)#write ASCII character
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    LCD.write_byte_data(address, IR, 0x01, force=None)#clear display
    LCD.close()

There is a new problem that has come up, when I run the above code, the LCD screen stays the same as it is at startup, a blue background. Next, to see if the issue was happening with my old original code where I had an extra for loop that I removed, and when I ran that code the screen turned right off instead of displaying the cursor sign and ≣ signal. So for some reason the outcome of the first code has changed without me modifying it at all.
Could anyone please help me to debug these issues, specifically why the LCD is turning off/not changing at all? I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

In the second code bit is not defined anywhere, so when you do (7 - bit) it should throw an exception, so the second code executes partially and then stops due to an unhandled exception.

@Cincinnatus Thank you for your reply. As I was trying to fix what you just pointed out, some new problems occurred. I removed the (7 - bit) but now there is no change to what the lcd looks like, still the blank blue screen whenever I run it. I then tried the old code with the extra "for bit in range(8):" loop and this was now causing the LCD backlight to turn off! Do you know what might be going on here? Thanks again!!

you should edit your question. Post the actual code you are executing and the problems you are facing. Don't explain changes in the comments, edit your code instead.

@Cincinnatus I've updated the original post. Thanks.

In the second version of the code, the line LCD.write_byte_data(address, DR, ord(char), force=None) gives an indentation error. It should be indented at the same level as the previous line, but it has an extra indentation that causes an error. Then why are you putting everything inside a try? Are you expecting the imports to throw a KeyboardInterrupt exception? If not, then those lines should not be inside the try block. The only things that should be inside a try block are those things that might throw the exception you are catching.

@Cincinnatus Sorry, that extra indentation was an error when pasting the code, it's not what I'm using in my raspberry pi. I've modified the code without the try and let you know how it goes.

Removing the "try:" and "except:" makes no difference.

I've resolved the issue.

By correctly indenting your code so it runs without errors?

no, I decided to use a premade LCD library.
